# Can you still do this in jquery 1.4?

Tags: jquery

I had this in jquery version 1.3

```
// ajax requests would get this method
 $().ajaxStart(function (e)
    {
        $('body').css('cursor', 'progress');
    });
```

Can you still do this. Every time I look though firebug and put break points these never get run. Do I have to move them now to the ajaxSetup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/):

> Whenever an Ajax request is about to
>   be sent, jQuery checks whether there
>   are any other outstanding Ajax
>   requests. If none are in progress,
>   jQuery triggers the ajaxStart event.
>   Any and all handlers that have been
>   registered with the .ajaxStart()
>   method are executed at this time.

Could it be that you have an Ajax request in progress?

EDIT: possibly use `$(document).ajaxStart` too instead of `$().ajaxStart`, saw this mentioned in the comments on the jQuery site.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this in 1.4:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function (e) {
    $('body').css('cursor', 'progress');
});
```

Pre 1.4 `$()` was a jQuery set containing `document`, now it is *actually* an empty set...so there's no element to bind the `ajaxStart` event to, you need to explicitly put `document` in there now.  You can find a [full list of breaking changes in 1.4 here](http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14#backwards).

Comment: @chobo2 - Updated the answer to add a bit more context

Comment: Hmm interesting. One more question how would I put ajaxStart in the ajax setup?

Comment: @chobo2 - Same way, just `$(document).ajaxStart()`, or shorter: `$(document.body).ajaxStart(function() { $(this).css('cursor', 'progress'); });`

Comment: Sorry I meant in $.AjaxSetup()